# How can the private key be obtained in PKI without alerting a third party?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure

For example, I sent a message to Ardi and encrypted it with Ardi's public key. Ardi must decrypt the message with his private key. How can Ardi's private key be obtained in PKI without anyone else knowing?

Thank you in advance for you answer.

Comment: The best is that you generate yourself the keys on a sufficiently secured computer. The trust on the security (freedom of backdoors and errors) of the software used to generate the keys could be an essential issue. To be safe, you have to carefully examine an open-source package for that. (BTW I have a fairly short code for RSA key generation available at s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7234475/1/ which you may like to look at.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ardi does not obtain his private key from the PKI. The PKI obtains Ardi's public key from Ardi.

Ardi owns a *public/private key pair*: a *public key* and a *private key* that "dance together" (they are two mathematical facets of a single object). The public key is meant to be public. The job of the PKI is to publish the public key, and offers some verifiable guarantees that a given public key is indeed Ardi's public key -- i.e. that the corresponding private key is under exclusive control of Ardi. In all of this, Ardi's private key never leaves Ardi's computer.

(To be complete, there are PKI models where the CA insists on generating the public/private key pair, and transmits the private key to Ardi through some one-time secured channel. This is a valid model for keys meant for encryption, because it allows the PKI to make a backup of private keys to avoid risks of data loss in case Ardi's computer burns down. However, the "normal" PKI model is that the key pair is generated by the key owner, the private key never being seen by the CA or anybody else.)

Comment: @user3528526 Don't forget to attribute your source. Of course, if this was a homework or an assignment question,... good luck!